# How to check for increase in LOC on commit?

Tags: java, svn, project, pmd, line-count

I've been tasked with finding a way of reporting whenever the LOC/file size of certain files in our project increases when someone tries to commit via SVN.

ie. if a file has 26 LOC and a developer increases this, they should be alerted at compile or commit time.

We already use PMD so I was hoping I could make use of a PMD rule to achieve this but having looked in to it I'm not sure if that's possible with PMD.

Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using Sonar?  It can calculate LOC measures, and produce reports that show changes over time.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, we do in fact already use Sonar. Do you know if it is able to give some sort of notification of the changes though, such as an email if someone increases the line count say? If so this may be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Umm ... no.  But why don't you just set SVN up to send a notification for ALL commits to the file?

Comment: Hmm, well we already make use of change-review emails among the team for changes to any file/s, in this case I'm looking for a more specific alert somehow.

Comment: I think you can do it on the SVN server already with commit hooks. You then could report a LOC change delta, but only if positive. A notifcation of that could be easily generated then.

Comment: Thanks Hakra, we're looking in to using this idea now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [JavaNCSS](http://www.kclee.de/clemens/java/javancss/).  It looks to have a sound notion of what a line of code is ... and it appears to be grammar based.  You may need to modify / extend / post-process to compare line count changes over time.

**UPDATE**

Looks like it only supports up to Java 5/6 language syntax.

---

Having said that, if you only want to do this for "certain files" (i.e. a small number), this strikes me as over-engineering.  And if you want to do it for large numbers of files, then one has to wonder if someone (your manager perhaps) has a clinical case of metrics obsession disorder.  (This is a delusional disorder where people imagine that software metrics are a valid measure of project progress ...)

Comment: The reasoning behind this as it was explained to me is that there are deprecated parts of the project based off of an old structure that is no longer in use, but which are currently still used by other parts of the project. However, we don't wish to keep adding to the problem by allowing people to keep adding to these deprecated sections.